# Display image depending on theme Dark/light (e.g Outlook.com)

Tags: php, html, email, themes

I'm building this new site and I'm doing now the email module, so I was testing sending email and so far so good but I noticed that when I use the Dark Theme on Outlook.com the logos or any image that the email contains get blacked out or something similar.

How can I work around this?

Comment: You can read a bit more about dealing with [dark more here](https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/dealing-with-outlook-coms-dark-mode-dd56a1c0fdbc)

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.